# Create a camera like SnapChat or Instagram from scratch (Android)

Tags: android, camera, instagram, photo, snapchat

I would like to create a camera with all the features like the SnapChat's one or instagram's one from scratch in Android-studio.

I searched online, but I didn't found anything useful.

Can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Google provides an example of implementation for the Camera2 api. Take a look at it, and you can start from it: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Comment: I have done a simple project using camera2 api for camera filters, you can have a look to get some idea about it http://github.com/arshadkazmi42/android-custom-camera-with-live-filter

Comment: I tried to import your version @Arshad but it gives me this error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.2-5309881.

Comment: @user3476509 haven't tried that code for some time, I will check it and will let you know, its not using latest build tools you might wanna downgrade your build tools and try